# getAsObject method doesn't get value of p:autoComplete

Tags: autocomplete, converters

I'm trying uses the converter in p:autocomplete, but the arg2 of getAsObject Method always is "".

below are my codes:

page xhtml:

```
<p:autoComplete id="Cliente" value="#{beanPedido.cliente}"
        converter="converterCliente"
            completeMethod="#{beanPedido.completarCliente}" var="cliente"
            itemLabel="#{cliente.login}" itemValue="#{cliente}"
            >
            <p:ajax event="itemSelect"
                listener="#{beanPedido.onClienteSelecionado}" />
        </p:autoComplete>
```

Bean:

```
private Cliente cliente;
private List<Cliente> clientes;
public Cliente getCliente() {
    return cliente;
}

public void setCliente(Cliente cliente) {
    this.cliente = cliente;
}

public List<Cliente> completarCliente(String query) {
    clientes = f.buscarTodosClientes();
    List<Cliente> clientesFiltrados = new ArrayList<Cliente>();

    for (int i = 0; i < clientes.size(); i++) {
        Cliente cli = clientes.get(i);
        if (cli.getLogin().toLowerCase().startsWith(query)) {
            clientesFiltrados.add(cli);
        }
    }
    return clientesFiltrados;       
}

public void onClienteSelecionado(SelectEvent e) {
        cliente = (Cliente)e.getObject();
}
```

Converter:

```
@FacesConverter("converterCliente")
```

public class ConverterCliente implements Converter {

```
@Override
public Object getAsObject(FacesContext fc, UIComponent uic, String value) {
    if (value!= null && value.trim().length() > 0) {
        try {

            Fachada f = Fachada.getInstancia();

            return (Cliente) f.buscarClienteLogin(value);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    return null;
}

@Override
public String getAsString(FacesContext arg0, UIComponent arg1, Object arg2) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}
```

}

When I debug it always return value=""

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Is this code for Android? What version are you using?

Comment: Hello. No, I'm using JSF 2.2 and primefaces. I can list the values in autocomplete field, but I can't get the selected value. thanks for your help